# Symantec Class 3 G4 intermediate certificate missing from ca-certificates/ca-certificates-java

Tags: apt, java, ssl

I hope that you can help.
I did a search and didn't find this exact issue.

A vendor of ours recently updated their SSL certificate using a Symantec intermediate certificate.  Our java process was no longer able to access the site due to PKIX path being invalid.

I ensured both packages were up to date, but this certificate is not present.
I was able to update our local certificate root store manually, but would like to see if this can be updated in the apt-repo.

Thanks for your help.

Bill Campbell

Comment: Sorry: OS = Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have the Symantec CA certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ direcotry. So, one thing what we can do is we can export the Symantec CA certificate from mozilla, since Mozilla and Chrome has Symantec CA certificates by default and you can put it under the directory /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/ with crt extension and update the path in /etc/ca-certificates.conf the run the command

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Then you should be able to access the website which is using the certificate signed by Symantec. Let me know if you need more on export CA from mozilla and import to ubunut ssl directory.